# Easiest way to put python text game in html?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to help someone put a python text game to be displayed with the inputs and output on his html website. What's the easiest way to do this, regarding the many outputs and inputs? Would it be to make it a flask app? I don't really know how else to describe the situation. Answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a website with python3.8 and Sanic. It was pretty to use `async`, `await` and `:=` ~